# Unresolved reference: viewModelScope - Android KTX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ktx

I'm trying to use the new `viewModelScope()` function provided by the new android ktx library.

In the gradle file, I've added:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```

but when I tied to access the `viewModelScope()`, I got `Unresolved reference: viewModelScope` error:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun fetchData(){
        viewModelScope.launch{

        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I am using lifecycle_version = "2.2.0". I am still getting the same error. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the release notes https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies

`viewModelScope` is available from `v2.1.x`

So you need to bump your version in your gradle file.

Comment: I am using lifecycle_version = "2.2.0", but the error is still persisting

Comment: @Nithinjith make sure you have `import androidx.lifecycle.*` in your source.

Answer (score 2):

I have use in my project [2.1.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.1.0-beta01):

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-beta01"
```

This is **less version then released on official site**.
However, I use it because new version [2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-alpha01) still has the `Unresolved reference: viewModelScope - Android KTX` error.